# On every deployment magento 2 folders and files permissions changed

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed magento 2 on it. When I'm deploying magento 2 site with

```
Php magento setup:upgrade
Php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I'm getting file permissions errors and HTTP 500 error.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option**

You **must execute the command from the owner of the web**, if for example the user of the web server is "www" you must execute these commands with this user and not with root.

**Second option**

Another option would be, after generating them, change pub static permissions with the command:

```
chown -R [USER WWW] pub/static/*
chgrp -R [GROUP WWW] pub/static/*
```

You must change [USER WWWW] and [GROUP WWW] for the values ​​of your server environment.

**Another possible option of error:**

Verify that the generic .htaccess exists in /pub/static/

**Example**

[image: Example]

In this case:

- First option, I need to execute the command with the user "edesarrollo"
- Second option:

  chown -R edesarrollo pub/static/*

  chgrp -R psacln pub/static/*